# Syntax error in my PHP form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Getting this error:

- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in
  D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\websitestuff\www\php-form-processor.php
  on line 9

The code:

```
$value = ($_POST['formEnquiry']) ? ($_POST['formName']) ? ($_POST['formTitle']) : '';
```

Comment: Ternary is: `?:` and not `??:`

Comment: @Rizier123 how do you mean?

Comment: As @Rizier123 says, unless you're trying to nest ternaries (really bad mistake) in which case you're missing a `:` and option

Comment: @DomJackson count the `?` in your line of code, there's 2 of them

Comment: @MarkBaker should I be adding another?

Comment: If you don't understand the ternary operator, write it as an `if` statement, and if you don't understand ternary operators, you certainly shouldn't try to nest them

Comment: Well you shouldn't add another `?` you should add another `:` if you want to nest the ternary operator. Take @MarkBaker advice. For just making an `if else` statement, which is more readable too.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to use two ternary operators, yet are not specifying an "else clause" for the first one. Breaking the code down:

```
$value = ($_POST['formEnquiry'])
         ? ($_POST['formName'])
             ? ($_POST['formTitle'])
             : ''
         // You're missing a ':' (else) statement here, like
         : ''
;
```

Writing it as procedural code, it would look like this:

```
if ($_POST['formEnquiry']) {
    if ($_POST['formName']) {
        $value = $_POST['formTitle'];
    } else {
        $value = '';
    }
} else {
    // Because of the way an assignment through a ternary works,
    // there needs to be an else here, since you already wrote $value =
    // Without an else value, it would end up like $value = ;
    $value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$value = ($_POST['formEnquiry']) ? ($_POST['formName']) ? ($_POST['formTitle']) : '' : '';
```